# Phonegap (Cordova) Scrolling with a data-position="fixed" header/footer only ios scrolling issue

Tags: jquery, ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have used the cordove 3.4

Phonegap (Cordova) Scrolling with a data-position="fixed" header/footer only ios scrolling issue

I have attached image file.![enter image description here][2]

[image]

Comment: How are you setting your meta viewport tag? Can you share some code?

Comment: You mean that jump after the scrolling? After the jump it comes down right?

Comment: not jump after the scrolling when i scroll up then footer are also with scrolling

Comment: <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no' />

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I tried reproducing the issue and was able to fix it with the below line of code. On your config.xml, you will need the below preference tag added, that should do.

```
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
```

Comment: lots of Thanks friends GenieWanted